# Android - Instance Variables

Tags: java, android

is it appropriate to define instance variables on the top of the class or we need to define them in onResume/onPause of the activity

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish?  Typically "instance variables" are members of the class and should be defined at that scope (the position in the file, i.e. top, doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the type of variable. There are some things (e.g. Views) that are not available until the layout is initialized. For others (e.g. resources) you need a Context so you'd have to wait until `onCreate` as well.

If you just want to define an integer or a String, namely, stuff that doesn't depend on the Android framework, go nuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining instance variables in your `onResume` method, then you are effectively re-assigning values to them everytime your `Activity` is resumed (and thus discarding any previous values). Define your instance variables in `onCreate`, which is called only once pr. `Activity` life-time.